# Nuxt-img src path not found

Tags: nuxt.js

I can't use the component `nuxt-image`, 404 not found. It may be something to do with the config but failed to look at the doc and tutos. Anyone ?

[image]

My `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,
  css: ['~/assets/styles/main.scss'],
  plugins: [
    {
      src: '~/plugins/locomotive.js',
      ssr: false,
    },
  ],
  loading: '~/components/Loading.vue',
  modules: ['@nuxt/http', '@nuxtjs/robots', '@nuxt/image'],

  image: {
    presets: {
      imgMin: {
        modifiers: {
          format: 'webp',
          fit: 'cover',
          quality: '60',
        },
      },
    },
  },

  robots: {
    UserAgent: '*',
    Disallow: '/admin',
    Allow: '/',
  },
  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/style-resources', '@nuxtjs/google-analytics'],
  pageTransition: 'fade',
}
```

My `package.json`:

[image]

My `template.vue`:

```html
<nuxt-img src="~/assets/medias/img/home/1.png" alt="image" preset="imgMin" />
```

Comment: The error is related to IPX, did you tried that one? https://image.nuxtjs.org/providers/ipx

Comment: 2 PS: `ssr: false` is obsolete, it's `mode: 'client'` now + images are forbidden, please post your `package.json` as actual text.

Comment: No, since i don't use a self hosted image provider. Only images from my local folder

Comment: Also, can you load your image with a classic `img` tag, does it work with it? If you only have static images, then you need to read that one again: https://image.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/static

Comment: Otherwise, as [explained here](https://image.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/providers#local-images), you need to put your images into `static` and not `assets`.

Comment: Yes it work perfectly fine with an "img" tag. The reason i used 'nuxt-img" is too have the 'format: webp'

Comment: At the end, my question is overall why do you have `ssr: false` + `target: 'server'` (default) for your app?

Comment: Good question, i am bad at config and back-end. I just like the Front and used a default config. i wanted to use the tag "nuxt-img" to be able to convert all my ".png " images to '.webp" format.

Comment: You should probably use `ssr: true` + `target: 'static'` and host it on Netlify/Vercel or alike. Will be free on top of that. Besides that, you can also follow my other comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73703697/nuxt-img-src-path-not-found?noredirect=1#comment130150651_73703697

Comment: Ok thank you Kissu for your help, i will look for a workaround.